# Angular CORS and workflow

Tags: node.js, angular, express, mean-stack

I have an Angular app on port 4200. I have the node server on port 300. I'm following a MEAN stack guide. To allow CORS, it suggests adding this to the server response:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.setHeader(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"
  );
  res.setHeader(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
    "GET, POST, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS"
  );
  next();
});
```

I have two questions:

1. Is this safe for deployment?
2. Is this a recommended workflow to access data from the server while in development? If it's this easy, what's the point of using Angular's in-memory-web-api-module?

Comment: Typically you use the [express cors middleware](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html)

Comment: For your questions: 1) To judge whether this is safe (or even necessary) you have to understand what CORS is (read about it) and decide whether you need it or not for your application. Typically, when you serve your API and frontend from different origins, you need CORS. To what level (ie allow all origins vs only a specific one) depends on your app 2) the in-memory-web-api may help you with developing your client because you don't need a working backend. But at some point, you probably want to test and access also your real backend ...

Comment: Your questions are much too broad and opinion-based for Stack Overflow - see the scope of the site defined in the [help/on-topic] as well as our [ask] guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can restrict the origin a bit more, like this :

```
 res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:4200');
```

instead of an asterisk.

When deployed, your header can be specified with your domain